# modify postgresql template with puppet

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I am using the `puppet`/`postgresql` module to install, configure and create my `postgresql` databases.

I am installing the `contrib` package and would like to enable the `uuid-ossp` extension. The catch for me is I would like to enable this extension in the 'template1' database. I would then use the `template1` DB as the source for all DBs that I create.

I couldn't find any hooks in this module to help me modify the `template1` DB. Is this possible?

I know that if I have a `postgresql` install already I can do the following:

```
psql -d template1 -c 'create extension "uuid-ossp";'
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like they have a provider named postgresql_psql that they use to set the encoding on template1.

Check how they use it in postgresql/manifests/server/initdb.pp, maybe it can help your use case also.